# Modifying Date-time Objects

Tags: php

Given the code below to add a month to a time and echo it:

```
<?php

$current_date = new DateTime('now');
$current_date = $current_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$Expiration_Date = new DateTime('now');
$Expiration_Date = $Expiration_Date->modify('+1 month');

echo $current_date;
echo $Expiration_Date;


?>
```

*Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string*

Why am I receiving this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to format your expiration date

```
echo $Expiration_Date->format("d-m-Y");
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Stefan and also you do not need to re-asign the DateTime object only simply modify it.

```
$Expiration_Date = $Expiration_Date->modify('+1 month');
```

Simply should be

```
$Expiration_Date->modify('+1 month');
```

That is not your error though, @Stefan has the answer for that.